# Can MongoDB changeStreams listen to system level collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.6, changestream, mongodb4.0

With the limited documentation available on MongoDB changestreams which they introduced version 3.6 onwards, I am not able to conclude if MongoDB changestreams let us listen to system collection changes.

Currently, I am interested in system.profile collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of MongoDB v4.0, you can’t open a change stream on internal [*database*.system.profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/#%3Cdatabase%3E.system.profile) collection.

The collection is reserved for internal use and is not included in the [replica set oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/), and because changestreams rely on the `oplog` it won’t be able to broadcast the change events.

Comment: Thanks Wan! Does this means that the only way to listen to system.profile will be querying it directy

Comment: Hi. Yes. Query on the ‘mongod’.